# Github pull request not showing all merge conflicts

Tags: git, github, merge

thank you in advance for answers. I use basic Github workflow for work but this scenario is stumping me.

Here are the background and sequence of events:

- There are 2 files in master branch: **file1** and **file2**
- `dev1` branch created from `master`
- someone else worked on another branch, `dev2`, which was also based on `master`
- `dev2` was merged into master, changes were made to both **file1** and **file2**
- I created a pull request for `dev1` after making a bunch of commits for both **file1** and **file2**, but none of them incorporated anything from `dev2` branch
- I'm expecting a lot of merge conflicts with `master` because `master` now has `dev2` changes and my `dev1` branch does not, but Github only showed merge conflict for **file1**, and *none* for **file2**.
- I manually compared `dev1/file2` versus `master/file2`, and there were indeed a lot of differences and I'm afraid the merge will overwrite `master/file2`
- Now I don't even trust the merge conflict report for **file1**.

So what am I doing wrong? How do I see all the differences between file1 & file2 from master branch versus my dev1 branch? My main concern is that I want to incorporate all the new changes in master branch into my dev1 branch and then there should not be any merge conflicts.

Comment: There seems to be a big misconception here. It is perfectly possible to edit a file in one branch and edit the "same" file in another branch and have zero conflicts. That is not what a conflict is. It is possible, out of a 2000 line file, for each party to edit 100 different lines and still have no conflicts. Or one. Or 100. It all depends on the details, eh. But the point is, I don't think you're envisioning correctly what a merge is or what a conflict is. 100 diffs could easily mean zero conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to matt's comment,

Git encounters a merge conflict only when it doesn't know which change to pick out of 2 ***conflicting changes***.

To give you an example, let's consider just 1 file, named `file1`, at version `v0` on the master branch. Let's say your peer makes changes to lines 1-10 of `file1` version `v0` and merges it. The file is now at version `v1` on master. But you are still working with version `v0`. There are 2 possible scenarios now:

1. You make changes to lines 30-50, say (or any other line other than lines 1-10). In this case, git merges your code with version `v1` automatically, to create a version `v2` with both your and your peer's changes. It uses the term `auto-merging` to denote this.

[image: Merging without conflicts]

2. You make ***conflicting*** changes to any of the lines between 1-10. If you make the exact same change as your peer, even then git will not show a merge conflict. If you do make a conflicting change, however, git needs to ask you which of the 2 changes is correct or the more preferred one, since it cannot decide for itself. This is why it shows a merge conflict in this case.

[image: Merging with conflicts]

Hope this helps you understand merge conflicts better.